# Identifyng vertices of different connected component in a forest result in forest?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph.
For every $X \subseteq E(G)$, denote $G[X] = (V(G), X)$.

Let $I,J \subseteq E(G)$.
Let $\cal P$ be a partition of $V(G)$ such that each part $\cal P$ corresponds the vertices that are connected in $G[J]$.
I know that $G[I \cup J]$ is a forest.
Moreover, $G[I]$ is a forest.

Since $G[I \cup J]$ is a forest, then each vertices pair $\{x,y\}$ in the same part of ${\cal P}$, we have exactly one path of $x$ to $y$ in $G[I \cup J]$.
Note that the path lies by the vertices of a same part of $\cal P$.

Is it true that if graph $G'[I]$ is obtained from graph $G[I]$ by identifying vertices of $G[I]$ inside the same part of $\mathcal{P}$
(this is, replacing each part of ${\cal P}$ by the one vertice and maintaining the original incidence),
then graph $G'[I]$ is still a forest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V(G)=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $I=\{15,46\}$, $J=\{12,23,34\}$. We have that $G=G[I\cup J]$ is a tree, $G[J]$ is a forest, and $\mathcal{P}=\{1,2,3,4\}\cup\{5\}\cup\{6\}$. If we identify vertices 1 and 4 which lie in the same part of $\mathcal{P}$, we obtain triangle $123\equiv423$.

Clearly, the triangle lies in a new graph, which is obtained from the graph $G$ by the specified operation.

At that, the graph obtained from $G[I]$ by the same operation will still be a forest. It follows from the fact that the edges of $I$ connect the parts of $\mathcal{P}$, and two parts are connected by no more than one edge.

Comment: But in this case, the cycle created lies by the edges of $J$. Considering only the edges of $I$ not create cycle after of the identifyng, correct?

Comment: In the question, I wish show that $G'[I]$ is a forest such that $G'$ is a obtained graph after of identifying the vertices. This is, not considering the edges of $J$.

Comment: @Thesco I added to my answer according to your comment. But I think it would have been correct if you had clarified this point in your question.

Comment: Ok, thank very you!

Comment: You're welcome. I edited your question a bit, I hope you don't mind.